# Python 'str' object has no attribute 'append' even when operating on list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

I keep getting this simple error which I can't see why. I'm trying to remove duplicate letters at same index in multiple plaintext but I get this letter which doesnt seem logical since `l` is an array of smaller arrays and these smaller arrays have a list as an element to say what unique letters found at this specific index. Note that the print return the list as supposed to be.

```
n = []
l = []
for x in range(83):
    l.append( [-1, [] ] )
print(l[0][1])
for x in solved_letters:
    if x[0] not in n:
        n.append(x[0])
        l[x[0]][0], l[x[0]][1] = x[0], x[1]
    else:
        for v in x[1]:
            if v not in l[x[0]][1]:
                l[x[0]][1].append(v)
```

sample of `solved_letters`

```
[[30, 'a'], [32, 'w'], [34, ' '], [36, 's'], [42, 'n'], [45, 'p'], ...]
```

Comment: Well, that means your assumption that you're dealing with a list **is wrong.** `print` the element in question to see it…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `solved_letters` second elements (i.e. `solved_letters[*][1]`) are letters and not lists so once you assign them in `l` in the following line - `l[x[0]][0], l[x[0]][1] = x[0], x[1]`, `l` will contain something line - `l[30][30, 'a']`. The next time you try to access it with the loop (i.e. `for v in x[1]`) you can iterate over a string but you cannot append since it is a string and not a list.

To overcome that I would change - `l[x[0]][0], l[x[0]][1] = x[0], x[1]` to - `l[x[0]][0], l[x[0]][1] = x[0], [x[1]]`.